# Employees first check in and last check out of every day for each employee attendance module odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am using odoo 13.

In the HR  attendance module,  employees in the system can check-in and check out multiple times per day. I want to get the first check-in and last checkout to the system for an employee per day. I want to duplicate the attendance view and add another view containing just the first check-in and the last check out for every employee each day as in the picture below. For instance: the employee Marc Demo has checked in two times today I want the first check-in and the last check out this applies to all other employees. This code for getting the first check-in  works for today record but previous records like yesterday don't with them. I have asked many people about this and they all told me to group attendance base on date I don't know how to do it so please help me. thanx in advance  [image]

```
@api.depends('check_in')
def get_first_check_in_time(self):
    first_sign_in = ''
    for emp in self:
        # attn_ids = self.env['hr.attendance'].search([('employee_id', '=', emp.id)])
        attn_ids = self.env['hr.attendance'].search([('employee_id', '=', emp.id), (
            'check_in', '>=', datetime.combine(fields.Date.today() , time(0, 0, 0)))])
        if attn_ids:
            for a in attn_ids:
                if not emp.first_sign_in:
                    emp.first_sign_in = a.check_in
                else:
                    first_sign_in = min(emp.first_sign_in, a.check_in)
                    emp.first_sign_in = first_sign_in
        else:
            emp.first_sign_in = False
```

Comment: I think just add all checkIns and checkOuts in two different list then apply max and min on those list.